# OData Error Response missing exception detail C#

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, odata, azure-web-app-service

I have C# WebApi2 project running on my localhost machine, if a OData error occurs, i receive the error in the following format

`https://localhost:44379/api/v2/events?$filter=1`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The $filter expression must evaluate to a single boolean value.",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "The $filter expression must evaluate to a single boolean value.",
      "type": "Microsoft.OData.ODataException",
      "stacktrace": "**STACKTRACE**"
    }
  }
}
```

However when I deploy this api to Azure webapp and to the exact same query, i get the following.

`https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/v2/events?$filter=1`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "An error has occurred."
  }
}
```

AT first i thought it may just be a setting for non-debug builds. I managed to override `ODataErrorSerializer` to add logging to try debug the issue further. However, after a closer look, It seems the parameter `graph` (which is  passed into this method https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/f9d10191efcb13fee7f995fa4ec2188860d8c6fd/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/Formatter/Serialization/ODataErrorSerializer.cs#L26 doesnt have the all the properties it usually has (stacktrace, innererror, etc). But this only happens when i deploy the code to Azure?

- I have tried running the code in debug mode
- Physically copying the dlls from my local machine to azure, in case it was an issue with a nuget package
- Overriding the default error serializer
- Disabling/Enabling any loggers, non-default media formatters

I have an exception logger which picks up the exception just fine (in Azure), but that same information is not present when handling OData errors it seems.

Is this maybe some sort of webserver (IIS) issue? I managed to get the stack trace of the http call, somewhere in here is where the data is entering the matrix. Has anyone ever encountered something like this?

`StackTrace: ' at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
 at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
 at MYAPI.EFODataErrorSerializer.WriteObject(Object graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter, ODataSerializerContext writeContext) 
 at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders)
 at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
 at System.Net.Http.ObjectContent.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
 at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
 at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
 at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response, IExceptionLogger exceptionLogger, IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.WriteResponseContentAsync(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response, IExceptionLogger exceptionLogger, IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<CopyResponseAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
 at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.CopyResponseAsync(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response, IExceptionLogger exceptionLogger, IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<ProcessRequestAsyncCore>d__12.MoveNext()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
 at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore(HttpContextBase contextBase)
 at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.BeginTask(Func1 taskFunc, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
 at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer was down-voted and deleted, so I will give it another go, in the hope that this is useful for someone:

1. In response to the question "Has anyone else encountered this?"

> then the answer is yes.  My team has observed the same problem.

2. As promised (in my deleted reply...), I did some further research and discovered that the application's customErrors mode is being honored by the o

> data error generator.  You *could* set `<customErrors mode="Off" />`
>   in your web.config but that could expose dangerous data to your
>   consumer, such as stack traces.

A better solution has been provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742121/how-to-control-presence-of-odata-error-details).